# Calling stored procedure with custom type using Ruby OCI8

Tags: ruby, plsql, oracle11g, oci8

Given (Using Oracle 11g and ruby-oci8 (2.1.6)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MOVIE.LISTING_TYPE AS OBJECT
(
 NAME VARCHAR2(255),
 DIRECTOR VARCHAR2(255),
 RELEASEDATE DATE,
 REVENUE NUMBER);


PROCEDURE CREATE_MOVIE_LISTING (
     p_listing      IN              LISTING_TYPE,
     p_id       OUT              NUMBER,
     p_review_text   IN              CLOB)
```

Is it possible to call this stored procedure using ruby-oci8?  How would one bind a hash as the custom datatype?